# .htaccess issue in wordpress 4.8.2

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am having images issue in my Wordpress version 4.8.2.

There is an `.htaccess` file in wp-content folder `public_html/wp-content/.htaccess`. When I rename or delete this file images work fine but the site breaks down

**.htaccess**

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
# END WordPress

php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to place this .htaccess file in root folder(public_html/.htaccess). Don't upload that file in wp-content folder. I hope it will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess will be on root not in wp-content folder . it should be in public_html